# Memory management when returning an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

In Objective-C, if I have a method in which I allocate and initialize an object, then return it, where/how do I release it?

for example, let's say I have a method where I create an object:

```
- (void)aMethod {
    UIView *aView = [self createObject];
}

- (UIView *)createObject {
    UIView *returnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return returnView;
}
```

When do I release this object? Or would I just autorelease it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [memory management objective c - returning objects from methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742397/memory-management-objective-c-returning-objects-from-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)aMethod {
    UIView *aView = [self createObject];
}

- (UIView *)createObject {
    UIView *returnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [returnView autorelease];
    return returnView;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [rules for memory management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) are clear on this matter. You should read them. Very simple, and fundamental for writing Objective-C code using Apple's frameworks.

Answer (score -6):

Remember also that Garbage Collection is not present on an iPhone so you can't autorelease if you are developing for that environment.

As to when you should release the object, the simple answer is when you are finished using it and before you destroy your application.

Comment: So in relation to my example above, would I release the object after I'm done with it in the `aMethod` method?

Comment: @jer I'm almost certain that garbage collection isn't in any iOS

Comment: @cobbal, http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/02_creatingProj.html

Comment: @jer from that link: "Platform: Mac OS X" a lot of mac stuff slips through into the iPhone docs

Comment: -1 autorelease is *for* the non garbage collected environment.  Of course you can use it there.  In fact, in GC, it's effectively a no-op.

Comment: **There's no garbage collection on iOS.**