# Creating an autoreleased object in a method and returning it to an instanced variable causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, object, return-value

I'm making a mess of creating an object in a method and returning it to a variable. As in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200413/memory-management-when-returning-an-objective-c-object) I know I should autorelease an object in this case, but when I do, it crashses.

I have written a method to create an array of images, and return this array. It looks like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createImagesFor:(NSString *)animName withFrames:(int)numberFrames {
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberFrames];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberFrames; ++i) {
        NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", animName, i];
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        [imageName release];
    }
    return imageArray;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
imageArray = [self createImagesFor:@"jumping" withFrames:2];
self.animationImages = imageArray;
[imageArray release];
```

However, when I run the build analyzer, it compiles but with the following complaint:

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line 109
>   1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
>   2. Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
>   3. Object allocated on line 109 is returned from a method whose name ('createImagesFor:withFrames:') does not contain 'copy' or otherwise starts with 'new' or 'alloc'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa (object leaked)

I've had a look at the [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) document but other than autoreleasing the variable (which crashes it), I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. This is how I autoreleased it:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberFrames]autorelease];
```

I've tried retaining the *imageArray as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742397/memory-management-objective-c-returning-objects-from-methods) like so:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
[imageArray retain];
    imageArray = [self createImagesFor:@"jumping" withFrames:2];
    self.animationImages = imageArray;
    [imageArray release];
```

But this also crashes.

The analyzer suggests I change the name of the method to something like 'newCreateImagesFor:withFrames:' but I don't see how this fixes things?

Thanks for the help.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    - (NSMutableArray *)createImagesFor:(NSString *)animName withFrames:(int)numberFrames {
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberFrames];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberFrames; ++i) {
        NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", animName, i];
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        [imageName release];
    }
    return imageArray;
}
```

returns an `imageArray` object that has a retain count of +1 but not auto-released, clang static analyser will warn you about this, and it is all to do with naming convention, because your method is not named to be like `newImagesFor...` or `allocImagesFor...` or `copyImagesFor...`.

---

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray;

[imageArray retain];
// sending message to nil, does nothing

imageArray = [self createImagesFor:@"jumping" withFrames:2];
// imageArray has a retain count of 1
// and it is an autoreleased object

self.animationImages = imageArray; 

[imageArray release]; 
// retain count = 0, will be dealloc'd, 
// however it is already in the autorelease pool, 
// it will be over-released at the end of current event run loop
```

When you declare `imageArray`, it is a null pointer to the class `NSMutableArray`, sending a message, in your case `retain`, to a null pointer in Objective-C is possible and will not throw an exception.

---

If you use a property accessor to cache your `imageArray` object, your property accessor should be declared to retain the object you assign to

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *imageArray;
```

---

Now that your method properly return an autoreleased `imageArray`, and you have a correct property accessor, all that's needed is

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray;
imageArray = [self createImagesFor:@"jumping" withFrames:2];
self.animationImages = imageArray;
```

Comment: Ok I see - I should be using properties to hold the autoreleased objects, and not over-releasing them. And since I'm using properties, I don't need to worry that they will be autoreleased too soon. Thanks!

Comment: "When you declare imageArray, it is a null pointer to the class NSMutableArray". Only un-initialized instance variables are guaranteed to be nil. Un-initialized local variables may be zero or may be some random number from the last time the block of memory it's stored in was used.

Comment: @Adam Ko : is it because the variable imageArray is a stack variable for the function and once the function call finishes the stack pointer is deallocated and further access using the deallocated pointer caused it to crash.

Answer (score 5):

You should change the last line of first block of code to `return [imageArray autorelease]` and get rid of the release in the second part (you normally don't ever need to release objects returned by method calls). That's what the analyzer complaints are about. However, I don't see why it would cause a crash.

How is the `animationImages` property defined? That might be the source of your problems.

Comment: Great - that makes sense. I was over-releasing the object which must have been causing the crash. And it works fine now, especially when I declare the property accessors, rather than instantiating on the fly. Thanks!