# Retain and release confusion?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memory management objective c - returning objects from methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742397/memory-management-objective-c-returning-objects-from-methods)

I have a confusion with retaining object. If I have an function that will return an object like this:

```
- (object) functionA {

   NSObject* o = [[object alloc] init];

   return o;
}
```

The object returned will have retain count of 1.... But is this best practice to do this or shall i put autorelease first and let the caller retain the object.

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710288/where-are-the-best-explanations-of-memory-management-for-iphone and the [official Memory Management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Answer (score 3):

In that case you'd return an autoreleased object. The NARC rule states that any method that does not include the words 'new', 'alloc', 'retain' or 'copy' should return a non-owning reference. The method `functionA` includes none of those words in its name.